# Add Geofence in a Service in android

Tags: android, google-maps, firefox, android-geofence

I have a very small usecase. User A uses Google-Maps and saves geofence co-ordinates for User B. Now I am using Firebase to save all the information related to this geofence and then my app-server sends all the geofence related data to User B's phone. However, I do not understand how to set the Geofence from `Firebase Messaging Service` without calling the `GoogleMapsActivity`. I would like to do it in the background. I tried to search a lot on this topic on the internet. But all the tutorials don't cover this area. If anyone can share and guide me on this problem that will be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to add some geofences in background service. Of course you can do it, just create a brand, new intent service to do that and pass required data to it.

Your service should implements `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`interfaces and inside `onCreate` method create `GoogleApiClient` object.

Inside `onHandleIntent` you should connect to `GoogleApiClient`and then inside `onConnected` callback method from `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` register your geofences.

To prevent the service from stopping when performing asynchronous registration methods, you can use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Some additional infos about [geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).